# Rails App Interface Architecture Design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, xmlrpclib

I have a rails application that serves as an interface to a hybrid of data. Most of the information I require is retrieved from the command-line program using XML-RPC. Aside from this, I require some additional bit of data which I have no option but to store in a database. For this reason, I am having trouble figuring out what would be the best way to design the application.

I have overridden `self.all` and `self.find(id)` such that they rely on calls to `super` and then "enrich" the object by defining its instance variables to the appropriate data retrieved from the program using XML-RPC.

This all seems pretty convoluted though. For example, I imagine I have lost the ability to use the magic finders (`find_by_x`), and I don't know if anything else will break as a result of this.

My question is if there is a more logical and sensible way of going on about doing this. That is, designing an application that depends on XML-RPC for its data for the most part, but also some data stored in a database.

I did read about `after_find`. Using this callback, I can implement the "object enriching" process and have it run anytime there is a found record. However, my method of retrieving data associated with an item is different than that of retrieving *all* item data. The way I do it for retrieving *all* item data (`self.all`) is way more efficient, but unfortunately not applicable, to retrieving only *one* item's data (`self.find`). This would work well if there were a way I could make the callback not apply to `self.all` calls.

Comment: Humble suggestion. Please be concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, you shouldn't mess with ActiveRecord's finders - there is a *lot* of magic that they rely on.

`after_find` is a great direction to start with, but if you're having issues with batching, then what I'd recommend is twofold - use a caching layer and `alias_method_chain` to implement a version of `#all` that performs your batched XML-RPC find, caches it, and then pass the call through to the unaliased original `all`. Then, your `after_find` would check your cache for data first, and if it's not there, perform the remote find. This would let you successfully batch data for `all` finds while utilizing the callback.

That said, there is probably an easier way to do this. I would just use models that don't descend from `ActiveRecord::Base`, but rather, which descend from some XMLRPC base interface, and then have faux associations on them that point to AR instances with your database information. Thus, you might have something like:

```
class XmlRpcModelBase
  ...

  def find(...)
  end

  def all(...)
  end

  def extra_data
    @extra_data ||= SomeActiveRecordModel.find(...)
  end
end

class Foo < XmlRpcModelBase

end
```

It's not ideal, and honestly, it's going to depend a lot on how much of this is read, and how much is read/write, but I would try to stay out of ActiveRecord's way where possible, and instead just bolt on the AR-related pieces as necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, the XmlRpcModelBase method seems more logical. Just a clarification though: If I currently have a model called Item which represents an Item from the command-line program, would that now derive from XmlRpcModelBase? Then what would be SomeActiveRecordModel, something like ItemPersisted -- that is, just a database representation of that model?

Comment: I'd have `Item` descend from your XmlRpcBase (since that really is the item's model), then have something like `ItemData` descend from AR. It's hard to say without knowing the exact nature of the data, though.

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I was thinking about doing after reading your response. Do you know of a way of going about renaming a model? I imagine I would have to create a migration to rename the table as well? Anything else I should keep in mind? That way I'll rename the existing AR-based one to ItemData, and make a new one, Item, derive from the xmlrpcbase.

Comment: You can use the `set_table_name` macro on an AR model to override the table name. You can just rename the file and the class appropriately, as well (or just generate a new model and copy your logic from the old one over!)